# Histogram Equalization of image using lookup table

Tags: java, image-processing, histogram

I am attempting to histogram equalize a grayscale image in Java. The description is as follows: Iterate over the image using one band of each pixel's RGB as the index of the look-up table to determine the new pixel value for the image. Set the RGB for each pixel to the RGB corresponding to the new pixel value.

Implementing this I get an image that is tinted blue:

[removed]

(Expected result)

[removed]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
private void histogramEqualize(BufferedImage im, int[] lut) {
     for (int x = 0; x < im.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < im.getHeight(); y++) {
                Color c = new Color(im.getRGB(x, y));
                Color eq = new Color(lut[c.getRed()], c.getGreen(), c.getBlue());
                im1.setRGB(x, y, eq.getRGB());
            }
     }
 }

public int[] getLookupTable(int[] h, int n) {
     // h: Histogram for im1 in either the red band or luminance.
     lut = new int[256];
     double sf = 255/n;
     int sumH = 0;
     int sk = 0;
     for(int i=0; i<h.length; i++) {
         sumH += h[i];
         sk = (int)(sf*sumH);
         lut[i] = sk;
     }
     return lut;
 }
```

I also tried changing `Color eq = new Color(lut[c.getRed()], c.getGreen(), c.getBlue());` to `Color eq = new Color(lut[c.getRed()], lut[c.getGreen()], lut[c.getBlue()]);` but this resulted in a black image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned that you want to apply histogram equalization on a gray scale image but you are using RGB color values of pixels.

For gray scale image you can normalize only gray scale levels in image for histogram equalization as below:

1) Iterate through each gray scale pixels values and generate a histogram data of each gray scale levels by counting their occurrences in the image.

2) Find the cumulative distribution of the above histogram.

3) Iterate through each gray scale pixel values in the original image and replace their values with the their corresponding normalized values using below formula.
[image: histogram equalization formula]

```
 where L=255, that is total gray scale levels,
 M = Image height,
 N = Image width,
 MxN to get total number of pixels in image.
 cdfmin = min value of cumulative distribution data in step 2.
```

This will get you the new normalized image matrix.

If you want to to apply histogram equalization on RGB image then you will need to to convert RGB color space to HSV color space and apply same steps as in gray scale image on value channels without changing their hue and saturation values.

Comment: Thanks so much; I got it.